# how to do dynamic loading in android?

Tags: android

i have an rss feed that comes via an XML. There are several events that are returned with information about them. The events are returned with tags...for eg: ....info...

as soon as i encounter  tag, i want to update the listview that i am using to show the events. 
So the user does not see the loading progress dialog, rather he sees the events getting added to a list.
How do i do this.

thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing this is best achieved if you do parsing in a separate Thread, assuming you're not doing it already, and from there add these items to UI once discovered.

Comment: i have heard of async task also and it is said that it is much more easier with it, than to make and manage your own thread....

Comment: Your use-case is a bit different from what AsyncTask is designed for (as I see it). It's good for handling e.g. image loading, as it provides easy to use interface to do loading in a separate thread, and another callback ran in UI thread to set it to ImageView. In your case you have long running Thread which triggers multiple UI calls.

Comment: ok.so how do i do what you are saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's pseudo codeish example for one way of doing this using SAX parser;

```
// MyParserThread is assumed to be inner class of Activity here.
private class MyParserThread extends Thread implements MyParserObserver {
    private MyParser mParser;
    public MyParserThread() {
       mParser = new MyParser();
       mParser.setObserver(this);
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            // load xml
            mParser.parse(xml);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
    public void onMyParserEvent(final DataReceivedFromParsing data) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                 // update data to your UI.
            }
        });
    }
    public void cancel() {
        mParser.cancel();
    }
}
```

And in your parser you're implementing [ContentHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#startElement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes%29)

```
public void cancel() {
    mCancelled = true;
}
public void startElement(....) {
    if (mCancelled) {
        // If you want to stop Thread from running, all you have to do
        // is make parsing stop.
        throw new SAXException("Cancelled");
    }
    ....
}
```

And triggering parsing once your onCreate is called would be;

```
public void onCreate(...) {
    ...
    mParserThread = new MyParserThread();
    mParserThread.start();
    ...
}
```

Now this isn't perfect but hopefully gives some idea how to do Thread handling for this purpose. Fundamentally you just have start it, and adding 'cancel' functionality is somewhat more of a bonus - e.g. for cases in which Activity is destroyed while your Thread is running.

Comment: ok. i was thinking this. Let the parser be in Async task. As and when data is parsed, it is put inside a database. Now this database is already associated with a listview before the parsing begins but notifydatasetchanged is set in its cursor adapter. This way i assume, the view will redraw itself..i have not tried it but i am just speculating.